# Move folder base on # of files in .bat

Tags: batch-file

ok so i have this

```
Game1
 1. Game1 track1.bin
 2. Game1 track2.bin
 3. Game1 track3.bin
 4. Game1.cue

Game2
 1. Game2 track.bin
 2. Game2.cue

Game3
 1. Game3.iso
```

so what i already have is this

```
for /r %%a IN (*.bin *.cue) do ( move /y "%%a" "E:\games\bincue" )
for /r %%a IN (*.iso) do ( move /y "%%a" "E:\games\ISO" )
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
```

Now this works fine but my issue is with multi track games. So is there a way to search each folder and if there is more then 2 files in that folder to move the folder to a different location?

Comment: Yes you could use a "For /d /r" to check the folders and implement a counter: set counter+=1 and then IF %counter% GTR 1 move "%%a" "DoubleBin"...Something like that.

Comment: ```FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /ad "*"') DO ( FOR /F %%c IN ('dir /b/a-d "%%~a" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') DO IF %%c gtr 2 MOVE "%%a" "E:\PS2\multibins" )
``` so something like this? found it in another post about wanting to split half the files. it works but not sure if it can be shrunk.

Comment: Yes, something like that.